# How to set tikz node size in terms of other coordinates?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need a way to get LaTeX to see that I'm trying to draw a node with it's borders set at coordinates. If I could tell it the diagonal angle to create a box around, or anything else to draw the shape on, I would. I have the following:

```
\node[draw,minimum width=1cm,below=.5cm of bytes] (byte1) {$6A$} ; %valid
\node[draw,minimum width=1cm,below=0pt of byte1] (byte2) {$00$} ; %invalid
\draw let \p1 = (byte1.north west),
    \p2 = (byte2.south west) in
    (\p1) -- (\p2) node [name=insn1,draw,left=of byte1] {push 0x0;};
```

What I actually want, however, is for `insn1` to be sized enough to contain each of `byte1` and `byte2`, but shifted to the left of each of them. What I have expressed, just makes `insn1` the size enough to contain the text `push 0x0;`, but to the left ob `byte1`. What I thought I got by using the `(\p1) -- (\p2)` part, was an edge around which to place the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\draw (\p1) -- (\p2)` just draws a line from `\p1` to `\p2`. Appending `node [...] {...}` to the end of such a path just places the node at the last coordinate in the path (here `\p2`). The path up to that point has no bearing on the size of the node itself. (In your case though the `left=byte1` takes precedence, and is what determines the position.)

For example with `\draw (0,0) -- (2,3) node{foo};` you get a line between the two coordinates, and the `foo` node is placed at `(2,3)`.

But what you can do is to use `\p1` and `\p2` to calculate the total height of `byte1` and `byte2`, and set the `minimum height` of the node to that value. Or you can use the `fit` library and its `fit` option. Both are shown below.

(Unrelated: If you don't want the double line width between `byte1` and `byte2`, set `below=-\pgflinewidth of byte1` in the settings for `byte2`. You currently have `below=0pt of byte1`.)

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,fit}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (bytes);
\node[draw,minimum width=1cm,below=.5cm of bytes] (byte1) {$6A$} ; %valid
\node[draw,minimum width=1cm,below=0pt of byte1] (byte2) {$00$} ; %invalid

\node [name=insn1,
       draw,
       fit=(byte1)(byte2), %make the node so large that these two fit inside
       inner sep=0pt, % and with zero padding, the fit is snug
       left=of byte1.north west, % this and the next line to align the tops
       anchor=north,
       text height=2.2ex % for better vertical alignment of the text inside the node
] {push 0x0;};


\path let
  \p1 = (byte1.north west),
  \p2 = (byte2.south west),
  \n1 = {\y1-\y2} %\yN is y-coordinate of \pN
  in
  node [name=insn1,
        draw,
        minimum height=\n1, % set minimum height to the calculated \n1
        right=of byte1.north east,
        anchor=north
        ] {push 0x0;};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

as supplement to nice [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%C3%B8rn-t) answer, without use of `fit` library:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 0mm and 10mm,
     N/.style = {draw, minimum width=10mm, align=center, outer sep=0mm}
                    ]
\node (byte1) [N] {$6A$}; %valid
\node (byte2) [N, below=0pt of byte1] {$00$}; %invalid
%
\path   let \p1 = (byte1.north),
            \p2 = (byte2.south),
            \n1 = {\y1-\y2} in
        node (insn1) [N, minimum height=\n1, % set minimum height by \n1
                      left=of byte1.south west,
                      ] {push\\ 0x0}
        node (insn2) [N, minimum height=\n1, % set minimum height by \n1
                      right=of byte1.south east,
                      ] {push 0x0};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A width/height of `\pgflinewidth` can be minused to be more accurate :-)